# PHP and MySQL are related to each other?

Tags: php, mysql

In what way PHP and MySQL are related to each other ?

I learnt SQL and never learnt PHP. I see web tools written in PHP used to perform all MySQL operations and I read that interacting with MySQL makes PHP a far more interesting tool. When are these two used together, or is it recommended to use them together ?

Comment: It very much depends what you are trying to do. PHP is a server side programming language, while MySQL is a database. They can be, and often are, used together, but that depends on the needs of the application your are trying to build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is a programming language that's primarily used for server-side web programming. MySQL is a relational database.

The reasons you see them used together are as follows:

1. Both are free and open-source
2. Both are widely available on most web hosts (even shared hosting providers)
3. PHP is used to create dynamic web pages, while MySQL is used to store and access data in a more convenient manner than flat files (see "why are databases better than flat files"). They play complementary roles on a server

Used together, you can create interesting, dynamic web sites (Wikipedia), applications (Facebook), and frameworks (Wordpress).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language. It can connect to many different database platforms.

MySQL is a relational database management system that can be used by PHP.

Since they are both open-source, this makes them very commonly used together. They are not exclusively used together and are independent tools.

Comment: Like Java and PHP are commonly used together "Since they are both open-source"?

Comment: @cpattersonv1 Huh? Since neither PHP or Java are a RDMS, you probably wouldn't use them together.

Comment: I know that, but your statement says that they're used together BECAUSE they are Open Source. I was pointing out that open source is a blanket covering several projects, not all of which are used together simply because they are open source.

Comment: I preluded with a definition of each tool. Does this not suffice for defining their exclusivity?

Answer (score 1):

They're only related as far as being Open Source. Open source is sort of a mindset that ["promotes free redistribution and access to an end product's design and implementation details."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source)

[PHP](http://www.php.net/) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) are commonly used together because PHP has APIs for connecting to and querying MySQL databases, such as [ODBC](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php), [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), an improvement on the original [MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions. Also most hosting companies will include an install for both in their Apache server install because both are actively supported by massive communities and used by major corporations. MySQL is licensed by Oracle, who also licenses Java (another open-source programming language).

Answer (score 0):

PHP requests are stateless. Database like MySql are useful to store static data (as well as XML files, for example). MySql is probably one of the most used *relational database system* out there. Not all PHP applications need a database at all, but they *usually* do.